# Assign default read-write cosmos db role by terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cosmosdb

i am totally fine with default read-write role provided by cosmos db by default. It's id is `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002`.

I write simple TF code to assing that role to function app:

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_role_assignment" "example" {
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_cosmosdb_account.profiles_cdb.resource_group_name
  account_name        = data.azurerm_cosmosdb_account.profiles_cdb.name
  role_definition_id  = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"
  principal_id        = azurerm_linux_function_app.syringe_function_app.identity[0].principal_id
  scope               = data.azurerm_cosmosdb_account.profiles_cdb.id
}
```

But that code throws:

````
Error: parsing "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002" as an SqlRoleDefinition ID: parsing Azure ID: parse "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002": invalid URI for request │ │   with azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_role_assignment.syringe_integration_cdb_playerprofiles_msi_readwrite, │   on main.tf line 323, in resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_role_assignment" "example": │  323:   role_definition_id  = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"

When i assing that role with `azure cli`:

``` az cosmosdb sql role assignment create --account-name profiles-cdb
--resource-group rg-shared-test --scope /subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/rg-shared-test/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/profiles-cdb
--principal-id <principal_id> --role-definition-id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002
````

it works like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried Assign default read-write cosmos db role by terraform as mentioned it require more information when compare to role assignment in Azure CLI.

You are facing a different issue with Terraform than the one that Azure CLI handles. Azure CLI lets you use the short form of the role definition ID, such as `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002` for the built-in role. However, Terraform needs the full Azure Resource Manager (ARM) ID for role definitions.

Azure CLI can resolve the short form of the role definition ID to its full ARM ID when you assign the role. However, Terraform needs the full ARM ID to be specified in the configuration, as it does not perform this resolution.

To correct your Terraform code, you need to specify the complete ARM ID for the role definition. This ARM ID usually follows this pattern: `/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseRoleDefinitions/{role-definition-id}`.

**My demo terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-cosmosdb"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  offer_type          = "Standard"
  kind                = "GlobalDocumentDB"

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level = "Strong"
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    failover_priority = 0
  }
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_role_definition" "example" {
  name                = "vksbsqlroledef"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.example.name
  type                = "CustomRole"
  assignable_scopes   = [azurerm_cosmosdb_account.example.id]

  permissions {
    data_actions = ["Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/items/read"]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_role_assignment" "example" {
  name                = "736180af-7fbc-4c7f-9004-22735173c1c3"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  account_name        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.example.name
  role_definition_id  = azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_role_definition.example.id
  principal_id        = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
  scope               = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.example.id
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

If you still wanna use your short format ID in your terraform configuration you can use a `null_resource` in Terraform to execute an Azure CLI command. A `null_resource` combined with `local-exec` provisioner can be used.

```
resource "null_resource" "example" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az cosmosdb sql role assignment create --account-name profiles-cdb --resource-group rg-shared-test --scope /subscriptions/${var.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/rg-shared-test/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/profiles-cdb --principal-id ${azurerm_linux_function_app.syringe_function_app.identity[0].principal_id} --role-definition-id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_linux_function_app.syringe_function_app]
}
```